# Should we chair a session in which we present?

Tags: conference, chairing

In a prestigious conference in my field, I am asked to chair a session. However,  in the same session, I have my own paper, should I chair this session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the conference has asked you, there is no reason not to. Of course, chairing can mean different things depending on the conference. It may be just introducing speakers or keeping them to a schedule, or it may be actually chairing a discussion. There are other possibilities, I suppose.

I don't foresee any conflicts in such a situation, though you may want to accept or defer any responsibility for it depending on your comfort level.

Comment: In my case, it is introducing speakers and keeping them on time (including me in case I accept). And yes, the conf. has asked me for it.

Comment: Good idea to turn the stopwatch over to another while you speak. Speaking last might also be easier to manage.